# HTML interpretation of Quotation mark: `"` vs `”`

Tags: html

Can someone explain what's going on for this code to produce green text:

```
<font color=”red”>Red, anyone?</font>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WGSNX/7/.  I assume it's something to do with the first `”` symbol, but why should HTML parse that differently to `"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character ” (U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) is very different from the character " (U+0022 QUOTATION MARK). The latter is defined to act as attribute value delimiter in HTML; the former has no special significance in HTML, it is just yet another data character.

Thus, the attribute value specified is `”red”`´, with the right double quotation marks included, a total of five characters. It is of course an invalid color value. The error recovery that browsers apply, and that is being standardized in HTML5, see HTML5 CR, clause [2.4.6 Colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#colors), is that any character that is not a hexadecimal digit is replaced by the digit 0, and then if the length of the string is not a multiple of three, 0 digits are appended to make it so. So first the browser converts `”red”` to `00ed0`, then appends `0` to get `00ed00`, a green color. This is then treated as if it were prefixed by `#`.

If you use e.g. the developer tools (F12) in Chrome to inspect the element, you will see that the styles for the `font` element have `color: rgb(0, 237, 0);`, which is an alternative notation for `#00ed00`. In Firefox, using Firebug, you will see it as `#00ED00`.

Answer (score 6):

It is simple:
  = ”red” 
  = 0red0 (" is not ascii so make 0)
  = 00ed0 (r is not hex so make 0)
  = 00ed00 (pad)

#00ed00 is green

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the conversion is happening is this:

The browser assumes that `”red”` is three hex values, each 2 chars long:
`["”r", "ed", "”"]`

Both `”r` and `”` are invalid, so they are cast to `00`, so you end up getting the color:

```
#00ed00
```

Which is green.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the `”` symbol means anything to HTML. Try using `"`.

Comment: The quotation caused a meaningful change the behavior of the program, therefore it means something to HTML.  U+201D was cast to zero in that context.

Answer (score 0):

If  the color value isn't equal to the keywords such as "red","blue" and so on，The browser assumes that value is three **hex values**, each 2 chars long just as John Hornsby said.
All the invalid chars be made 0.
IF the color value length less then 6 ,the zero will be appended in the end.